# When goods receiving updating stock table

Tags: c#, sql

I have three tables Good Receive header ,Good Receive Details table and stock Table

```
  TB_GoodsReceive_HDR  - Header Table
  ID  SupplierID
  1     1

  TB_GoodsReceive_DTL - Details Table
   ID  GR_HDR_ID       ItemID   WarehouseID   ExpiryDate    Qty
   1      1               1       1     4/4/2012     20
   2      1               2       1     4/4/2012     30

   TB_Stock - Stock Table
   ID ItemID  WarehouseID   ExpiryDate  StockType  GR_HDR_ID    Qty
   1   1           1    4/4/2012       R       1        20
   1   2           1    4/4/2012       R       1        30
```

I have received Item 1 – 20 Qty and Item2  - 30 Qty. Same I have it in my stock table. 
There are lot of scenarios , But I need guidelines for this scenario

Now when user updates the TB_GoodsReceive_DTL  as below: Updating the item only(ItemID 1 to ItemID 3)

```
      ID GR_HDR_ID   ItemID    WarehouseID ExpiryDate    Qty
       1   1          **3**      1      4/4/2012     20
       2   1            2        1      4/4/2012     30

      My stock table values should be as follows: 

      ID  ItemID  WarehouseID ExpiryDate StockType  GR_HDR_ID    Qty
      1    **3**        1     4/4/2012       R        1      20
      1    2            1     4/4/2012       R        1      30
```

But my below stored procedure inserts the new row rather updating the row in the stock master.
Likewise user might update the warehouse or expiry date

The below procedure does the following:

Whenever the goods are received it will check the itemid, warehouse and expirydate in the stock table,if exists it will add the QTY else it will insert the new item in stock table.

The Problem is whenever the Good Receive table is updated(means when user updates ItemId or Expiry Date or Warehouse) how to update the stock table.
Please help me guys, its breaking my head...

```
    Declare     
    @ItemID int,
    @WareHouseID int,
    @Qty int,
    @StockType nvarchar(30),
    @ExpiryDate datetime,

    @IsExistsItem int,
    @IsExistsWH int,
    @IsExistsExpiryDate int,
    @IsGR_HDR_ID int,
    @GR_HDR_ID int

    set @ItemID=1
    set @WareHouseID=2
    set @Qty=20
    set @StockType='R'
    set @GR_HDR_ID=2
    set @ExpiryDate = '4/4/2012 12:00:00 AM'

    set @IsExistsItem = (select count(ItemID) from TB_Stock_Details where    
    ItemID=@ItemID)   
    set @IsExistsWH = (select count(WareHouseID) from TB_Stock_Details where   
    WareHouseID=@WareHouseID)
    set @IsExistsExpiryDate = (select count(ExpiryDate) from TB_Stock_Details where  
    ExpiryDate=@ExpiryDate)

if(@StockType='R')
    begin
        IF (@IsExistsItem>0) and (@IsExistsWH>0) and (@IsExistsExpiryDate>0)
            BEGIN
                  UPDATE TB_Stock_Details
                   SET
                      Qty =Qty + @Qty
                   WHERE ItemID = @ItemID and GR_HDR_ID = @GR_HDR_ID 
            END
        ELSE
            begin
                INSERT INTO TB_Stock_Details(ItemID,WareHouseID,Qty,StockType,ExpiryDate)
                VALUES(@ItemID,@WareHouseID,@Qty,@StockType,@ExpiryDate)    
            end         
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all after the UPDATE you have two end statements, one is enough.

The reason why the quantity is not increased is because when you insert to the stock details table, you do not set the value for the GR_HDR_ID column. In your update command you set a filter on GR_HDR_ID, but the condition never will be satisfied because it has no value in your table.

**edit:**

For the scenario you described you need both the old and the new values as parameters, and based on these you can update the stock table too. Without these you cannot know what should be changed, you just get a bunch of new data.

A better alternative for this is to create an update trigger on TB_GoodsReceive_DTL table, in which you have access both the old a new values (inserted and deleted tables) and can update related records in the Stock table.

Comment: Hi Norbip Thank you so much for replying.

Comment: Hi Norbip Thank you so much for replying. My doubt is when user updates the good receive table which means if he change ItemId(not the qty) from 1 to 2 then in the stock table must update the itemId only not the qty.Likewise user may change warehouse or expirydate as well. By mistake I have put two end statements,I will remove it.

Comment: How does your app's logic exactly work? I guess from the table names, that you have to keep the stocks table up to date based on incoming goods receives (so your users can see how much stock they have from X item), meaning that for a stock item you can have more goods receive associated (1:N relation). Is this correct?

Comment: Certainly, you are right. For one stock item there are more than one goods received associated.
TB_GoodsReceive_HDR  - Header Table
ID  SupplierID
1     1
TB_GoodsReceive_DTL
ID GR_HDR_ID   ItemID WarehouseID ExpiryDate Qty
1   1                     1 1  4/4/2012  20
2   1                     2 1  4/4/2012  30
TB_Stock
ID ItemID WarehouseID ExpiryDate StockType GR_HDR_ID Qty
1   1                     1 4/4/2012       R   1       20
1   2                     1 4/4/2012       R   1       30

Comment: I have received Item 1 – 20 Qty and Item2  - 30 Qty. Same I have it in my stock table. 
There are lot of scenarios , But I need guidelines for this scenario
Now when user updates the TB_GoodsReceive_DTL  as below: Updating the item only(ItemID 1 to ItemID 3)
ID GR_HDR_ID   ItemID WarehouseID ExpiryDate Qty
1   1                     3 1  4/4/2012  20
2   1                     2 1  4/4/2012  30

Comment: My stock table values should be as follows: 
ID ItemID WarehouseID ExpiryDate StockType GR_HDR_ID Qty
1   1                    3 4/4/2012       R   1       20
1   2                     1 4/4/2012       R   1       30
But my above stored procedure inserts the new row rather updating the row in the stock master.
Likewise he might update the warehouse or expiry date

Comment: You don't have to write all of the logic into one procedure. You could write a new stored procedure which would handle the update scenario you described. If an user changes the ItemID, you have to do two updates: reduce quantity in the old item's stock data, and increase it in the new one (and you can also update other columns you want). As a side note, row data is not so clear without any formatting in comments, its better if you edit your original question with additional data. :)

Comment: I have edited the original question.please do refer the original question

Comment: For the scenario you described you need both the old and the new values as parameters, and based on these you can update the stock table too. Without these you cannot know what should be changed, you just get a bunch of new data. A better alternative for this is to create an update trigger on TB_GoodsReceive_DTL table, in which you have access both the old a new values (inserted and deleted tables) and can update related records in the Stock table.